# one of my def variables is stuck at the same value

Tags: python-3.x, python-turtle

*I am new to python and this website*
*I am having difficulties understanding why I'm getting the same value from my Car.name function

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        Car.name = name
        Car.price = price
```

*I have stored some cars data in the class*

```
Lamborghini_Centenario = Car("Lamborghini Centenario", 2500000)
Rolls_Royce_Sweptail = Car("Roll's-Royce Sweptail", 12800000)
McLarenP1LM = Car("McLaren P1 LM", 3600000)
Koenigsigg = Car("Koenigsigg CCXR Trevita", 4800000)
Lykan_Hypersport = Car("Lykan Hypersport", 3400000)
Lamborghini_Veneno_Roadster = Car("Lamborghini Veneno Roadster", 4500000)
Aston_Martin_Valkyrie = Car("Aston Martin Valkyrie", 3200000)
Bugatti_Chiron = Car("Bugatti Chiron", 2700000)
Pagani_Huayra_BC = Car("Pagani Huayra BC", 2800000)
Ferrari_Sergio = Car("Ferrari Pininfarina\n      Sergio", 3000000) <--.
                                                                      |
#But when I try to get the name of a random car                       |
#Here is the code I used vvv (Carlist is not shown here)              |                    
#b = random.choice(carlist)                                           | ignore arrow not part of 
#b.name                                                               | code(sorry couldn't come
#it only gets the name from the bottom of the car data area.  --------+ up with a name)
#I have switched it up and have only been getting the bottom value
#it might be due to the turtle module .mainloop() function
```

*here is the whole script*
*Thanks in advance*

```
import random
import turtle
import os
import time

class Car:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        Car.name = name
        Car.price = price

higher_true = 0
lower_true = 0
lives1 = 1
score = 0

Lamborghini_Centenario = Car("Lamborghini Centenario", 2500000)
Rolls_Royce_Sweptail = Car("Roll's-Royce Sweptail", 12800000)
McLarenP1LM = Car("McLaren P1 LM", 3600000)
Koenigsigg = Car("Koenigsigg CCXR Trevita", 4800000)
Lykan_Hypersport = Car("Lykan Hypersport", 3400000)
Lamborghini_Veneno_Roadster = Car("Lamborghini Veneno Roadster", 4500000)
Aston_Martin_Valkyrie = Car("Aston Martin Valkyrie", 3200000)
Bugatti_Chiron = Car("Bugatti Chiron", 2700000)
Pagani_Huayra_BC = Car("Pagani Huayra BC", 2800000)
Ferrari_Sergio = Car("Ferrari Pininfarina\n      Sergio", 3000000)

carlist = [Lamborghini_Centenario, Rolls_Royce_Sweptail, McLarenP1LM, Koenigsigg, Lykan_Hypersport, Lamborghini_Veneno_Roadster, Aston_Martin_Valkyrie, Bugatti_Chiron, Ferrari_Sergio, Pagani_Huayra_BC]

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.screensize(1000, 500)
wn.title("Higher or Lower: Car Price Edition")
wn.setup(1050, 650, 0, 0)

Higher = turtle.Turtle()
Higher.penup()
style = ('Courier', 55, 'italic')
Higher.color('black')
Higher.goto(130, -300)
Higher.write('Higher', font=style, align='center')
Higher.hideturtle()

Or = turtle.Turtle()
Or.penup()
Or.color('black')
Or.goto(275, -300)
Or.write('or', font=style, align='center')
Or.hideturtle()

correct = turtle.Turtle()
correct.penup()
correct.color('green')
correct.hideturtle()

Lower = turtle.Turtle()
Lower.penup()
Lower.color('black')

Lower.goto(406, -300)
Lower.write('Lower', font=style, align='center')
Lower.hideturtle()

line = turtle.Turtle()
line.goto(0, 0)
line.shape('square')
line.shapesize(500, 0.5)
line.color('black')

Lives = turtle.Turtle()
Lives.penup()
Lives.color('black')
style = ('Courier', 60, 'italic')
Lives.goto(158, 260)
Lives.write('Lives:', font=style, align='center')
Lives.hideturtle()

Scores = turtle.Turtle()
Scores.penup()
Scores.color('black')
Scores.goto(-258, 260)
Scores.write('Score:', font=style, align='center')
Scores.hideturtle()

wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Lamborghini_Centenario.gif"))
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/RollsRoyceSweptail.gif"))
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/McLaren-P1-LM.gif"))
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Koenigsegg-CCRX-Trevita.gif"))
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Lamborghini-Veneno-Roadster.gif"))
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Aston-martin-Valkyrie.gif"))
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Bugatti-Chiron.gif"))
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Pagani-Huayra-BC.gif"))
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Ferrari-Pininfarina-Sergio.gif"))
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Lykan-Hypersport.gif"))

BugattiChiron = turtle.Turtle()
BugattiChiron.penup()
BugattiChiron.shape(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Bugatti-Chiron.gif"))
BugattiChiron.goto(-300, 0)

Carname = turtle.Turtle()
Carname.penup()
Carname.color('black')
Carname.goto(-300, -200)
style1 = ('Courier', 40, 'italic')
Carname.write("Bugatti Chiron", font=style1, align='center')
Carname.hideturtle()


def screenclick(x, y):
    print(x, y)
    if x in range(39, 227) and y in range(-290, -250):
        higher_true + 1


wn.listen()
wn.onscreenclick(screenclick)

a = Bugatti_Chiron
b = random.choice(carlist)
bname = turtle.Turtle()
bname.penup()
bname.goto(275, -200)
bname.write(b.name, font=style1, align='center')
# problem   ^^^^^^ is here(it's just giving the Car.name of Ferrari_Sergio)
while higher_true == 0:
    wn.update
    while higher_true == 1:
        if b >= a:
            score = score + 1
            correct.write('Correct!', font=style, align='center')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            correct.clear()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set attributes on the object and not on the class.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
```

`Car.name` will set a `name` attribute on the `Car` class. You would be able to access the `name` attribute from the `Car` class directly without using objects like `Car.name`.

Setting `Car.name` every time updates the `name` attribute of the `Car` class and it gets updated every time you create a `Car` object. Hence, it retains only the last value.